# how to delete local file in ftp inbound-channel-adapter of Spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have a integration case that get xml payload from FTP then use http outbound channel to sent the payload to webservice, ftp inbound-channel-adapter has a mandatory attribute named local-directory, remote ftp files will be downloaded here, however when I restart, seems all files in local-directory will be handled again, may I know how to avoid this?
One possible way is to  delete local file in ftp inbound-channel-adapter, how to do it, can you advise?

thanks

My Spring integration configurations

```
<ftp:inbound-channel-adapter
        channel="requestChannel"
        session-factory="ftpClientSessionFactory"
        remote-directory="/outbound"
        local-directory="/temp"
        auto-create-local-directory="true"
        delete-remote-files="false"
        filename-pattern="*.xml"
        temporary-file-suffix=".writing">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5000" max-messages-per-poll="10"/>
</ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>


<int:chain id="inboundChain" input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="replyChannel">

    <int:transformer ref="xmlToJsonTransformer" />
    <int:transformer ref="jsonToMapTransformer" />
    <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json" overwrite="true"/>
    </int:header-enricher>
    <http:outbound-gateway  expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                           url="http://localhost:8080/postService/postupdate"
                           http-method="POST"
                           extract-request-payload="true"
                            request-factory="requestFactory">
    </http:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to the outbound gateway to remove the file. See the [Expression Evaluating Advice Demo in the retry-and-more sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more#expression-evaluating-advice-demo) for an example - it removes or renames the file, depending on success or failure.

Comment: seems it doesn't work after I added ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice  into my http:outbound-gateway, can you share more details? is it due to my outbound gateway is http?
 <http:request-handler-advice-chain>
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                    <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />
                </bean>
            </http:request-handler-advice-chain>

Comment: Don't put config in comments; it's hard to read. Edit the question instead. `"payload.delete()"` - the payload is no longer a file; you need to add a header enricher before the first transformer - copy the payload to a header `name="file_originalFile" expression="payload"`. Then, in your advice, use `headers['file_originalFile'].delete()`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Gray's advise, here is my corrected configuration

```
<int:chain id="inboundChain" input-channel="requestChannel" output-channel="replyChannel">
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="file_originalFile" expression="payload"/>
            <int:header name="file-name" expression="payload.name"/>
            <int:header name="file-failed-path" value="/project/ftp/failed/"/>
            <int:header name="Content-Type" value="application/json" overwrite="true"/>
        </int:header-enricher>

        <int:transformer ref="xmlToJsonTransformer" />
        <int:transformer ref="jsonToMapTransformer" />

        <http:outbound-gateway  expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                               url="http://localhost:8080/postService/postupdate"
                               http-method="POST"
                               extract-request-payload="true"
                                request-factory="requestFactory">
            <http:request-handler-advice-chain>
                <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
                    <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="headers['file_originalFile'].delete()" />
                    <property name="onFailureExpression"
                              value="headers['file_originalFile'].renameTo(new java.io.File(headers['file-failed-path']+headers['file-name']))"/>
                </bean>
            </http:request-handler-advice-chain>
        </http:outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bean of ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice and set setOnSuccessExpression as payload.delete

```
  @Bean
  public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice deleteLocalFileAdvice() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice handlerAdvice =
        new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    SpelExpressionParser spelParser = new SpelExpressionParser(); 
    handlerAdvice.setOnSuccessExpression(
    spelParser.parseExpression("payload.delete"));
     return handlerAdvice;
  }
```

and provide the bean in adviceChain of MessageHandler

```
  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpChannel", adviceChain = 
  "deleteLocalFileAdvice")
  public MessageHandler ftpMessageHandler() {
    //process indbound file
  }
```

and provide the channel to your @InboundChannelAdapter

```
  @Bean
  @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "ftpChannel", poller = Poller(fixedDelay 
   = "3000"))
  public MessageSource<File> ftpMessageSource() {
    // MessageSource config..
  }
```